# What is the difference in setState callback syntax here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was having trouble with the state not being set by the time the callback function was called.  But I am unsure why the 2nd option below worked rather the first one I tried.  I thought setState's callback took a function.

```
function handleSendData() {

    console.log(this.state.experimentName)

}



//1st try was this.  Doesn't the callback in setState take a function, which I am giving it?  

this.setState({
  testChoice: testChoice,
  experimentData: experimentData
}, this.handleSendData())


//2nd try works but I don't know why I have to give setState's callback a function inside of a function.  

this.setState({
  testChoice: testChoice,
  experimentData: experimentData
}, () => {
  this.handleSendData()
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example, you are passing in the **result** of a function, not the actual function itself.

so it should look like:

```
this.setState({
  testChoice: testChoice,
  experimentData: experimentData
}, this.handleSendData)
```

Comment: all of the responses below were spot on and helpful but this one made things click for me...thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your first try you immediately call the `this.handleSendData` and give the return value to the `setState`. The correct way would be to remove the `()` and so pass the function as a reference to be called when the state is set.

It should be

```
this.setState({
  testChoice: testChoice,
  experimentData: experimentData
}, this.handleSendData) // removed the ()
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is thinking that `this.handleSendData()` is a function, and it is not, it is the result of the execution of a function.

for example

```
function sum(){
    return 2 + 2;
}
```

`sum()` is `4` which is not a function, is the result of the function, the function is `sum`

so basically you can do the following:

1) send the anonymous function as you did on your 2dn try.

```
this.setState({
  testChoice: testChoice,
  experimentData: experimentData
}, () => {
  this.handleSendData()
})
```

2) send the function instead of executing it:

```
this.setState({
  testChoice: testChoice,
  experimentData: experimentData
}, this.handleSendData)
```

Answer (score 1):

in the first example, `this.handleSendData()` gets called immediately :

```js
const fn = callback => {
  console.log('in Fn');
  callback();
}

const handleSendData = a => {
  console.log('in handleSendData')
}

fn(handleSendData())
// notice in handleSendData logged before Fn
```

when you pass the reference like `handleSendData` , it gets aclled inside `fn()`

```js
const fn = callback => {
  console.log('in Fn');
  callback();
}

const handleSendData = a => {
  console.log('in handleSendData')
}

fn(handleSendData)
```